# Eager Loading for Nested eloquent relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am creating a laravel application which is Item Warranty System.

There are 3 module involved, which is Item, Warranty and Claim.

```
Item -> Warranty -> Claim
```

Item has Many Warranty,

One Warranty Belongs to One Item,

Warranty have many Claim (because it can be claimed many time, claim is a model here because it have description)

One claim belong to one Warranty.

So now I am going to find how much claim does each item have, using eager loading? Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item **hasMany** Warranty

Warranty **hasMany** Claim

And now you want to get a Claims of a particular item. Then you need to make another relation in Claim Model as **Has Many Through**

```
class Item extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the claim for the item.
     */
    public function claims()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Claim', 'App\Warranty');
    }
}
```

Now in the controller you can use **withCount** method to count.

```
$ietms = App\Item::withCount('claims')->get();
```

Read more about [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Answer (score 0):

### Eager loading nested relationships:

```
 $ietms = App\Item::with('Warranty.Cliam')->get();
```